# Coldfusion Session Timeout 1 Hr Minute Warning

Tags: coldfusion

I have an application.cfc where I tell the program that I want the session timeout to be one hour like so:

```
<cfset this.sessionTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#">
```

Then on other pages I try to set up a warning when the timeout is going to end by doing

```
<!---Session Timeout Warning Pop up set to 1 hour--->
        <cfset sessionTimeout = 60>

<!---Warning 1 minute before Session will timeout--->

    <script>
        <cfoutput>
            var #toScript((sessionTimeout-1)*60*1000,"sTimeout")#
        </cfoutput>
        setTimeout('sessionWarning()', sTimeout);

        function sessionWarning() {
            alert('ATTENTION: Your session will time out shortly do to inactivity.');    
        }
    </script>

<!---End of Warning--->
```

For some reason the time out is not timing out at 59 minutes. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tested your code with the sessionTimeout var set to 2 instead of 60 and after a minute it showed the popup. What browser are you using? Also, are you sure you waited long enough?

Comment: I suggest troubleshooting with a value of 2 or 3 instead of 60.

Comment: You'd want the timeout in the JavaScript to be less than the actual sessionTimeout value else you're just showing the alert when it has timed out.

Comment: If you have the session timeout set to 1 hour, why would you expect it to timeout at 59 minutes?

Comment: Also....you do not need to use `toScript()` to output the number of milliseconds in JavaScript. You can simply do `var sTimeout = #(sessionTimeOut-1) * 60000#;`

Comment: Sessiontimeout-1 * 60 * 1000 is 59*60*1000 ... isn't that 59 minutes?

Comment: Oh... never mind I see you are AIMING at 59 minutes - trying to give them the 1 minute warning.

Comment: Zane - what else is on your page? are you using ajax for example? lots of things can keep your session alive.

Comment: well my final result of what I am trying to do is have the warning pop up then if a minute goes buy and there still idle I want it to automatically restart them on the first page again timing them out

Comment: won't the alert hold things up? once thats popped up, don't you loose control - you wont be able to 'automatically restart them on the first page' because the alert will be stuck there!?

Comment: it allows them to hit ok and still fill in the rest

Comment: then breaks when they try to submit